# Azure App Service - How to use environment variables in docker container?

Tags: azure, docker

I'm using an Azure App Service to run my docker image. Running my docker container requires using a couple of environment variables. Locally, when I run my container I just do something like:

```
docker run -e CREDENTIAL -e USERNAME myapp
```

However, in the Azure App Service, after defining CREDENTIAL and USERNAME as Application Settings, I'm unsure how to pass these to the container. I see from the logs that on startup Azure passes some of its own environment variables, but if I add a startup command with my environment variables, it tacks it on at the end of the one generated by Azure creating an invalid command. How can I pass mine to the container?

Answer (score 3):

As I understand you want to set environment variables in that docker container with -e option.
You don't need to use startup command for that. Pass these variables as application settings:
[image: app settings]

> Application Settings are exposed as environment variables for access by your application at runtime.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal)