# NodeJS and Express app error after deploy on azure web apps

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

After deploying node app with azure web app. An error appers about npm start. Project structure is simple app.js is like index.js.
App cant find a moongose module /helpers/simpleValidator.
I set up those variables in azure app config.

Environments variables

[image]
[image]

Logs

```
  2022-08-21T02:25:53.042096825Z {"code":"MODULE_NOT_FOUND","level":"error","message":"Cannot find module './helpers/isSimpleValidator'\nRequire stack:\n- /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/mixed.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/index.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/models/user.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/routes/user.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/startup/routes.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/app.js Cannot find module './helpers/isSimpleValidator'\nRequire stack:\n- /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/mixed.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/index.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/models/user.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/routes/user.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/startup/routes.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/app.js","requireStack":["/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js","/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/mixed.js","/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js","/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js","/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/index.js","/home/site/wwwroot/models/user.js","/home/site/wwwroot/routes/user.js","/home/site/wwwroot/startup/routes.js","/home/site/wwwroot/app.js"],"stack":"Error: Cannot find module './helpers/isSimpleValidator'\nRequire stack:\n- /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/mixed.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/index.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/models/user.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/routes/user.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/startup/routes.js\n- /home/site/wwwroot/app.js\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)\n    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)\n    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)\n    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)\n    at Object. (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:13:27)\n    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)\n    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)\n    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)\n    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)"}
2022-08-21T02:25:53.082240581Z npm info lifecycle t******@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
2022-08-21T02:25:53.120536311Z npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2022-08-21T02:25:53.120575311Z npm ERR! errno 1
2022-08-21T02:25:53.120582912Z npm ERR! t******@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
2022-08-21T02:25:53.120587512Z npm ERR! Exit status 1
2022-08-21T02:25:53.120591912Z npm ERR! 
2022-08-21T02:25:53.120596112Z npm ERR! Failed at the t******@1.0.0 start script.
2022-08-21T02:25:53.120600812Z npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2022-08-21T02:25:53.213953705Z npm timing npm Completed in 18684ms
2022-08-21T02:25:53.213985605Z 
2022-08-21T02:25:53.213992305Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-08-21T02:25:53.213997205Z npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-08-21T02_25_53_117Z-debug.log
    2022-08-21T21:37:11.468408816Z npm ERR! taap@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
    2022-08-21T21:37:11.469692437Z npm ERR! Exit status 1
    2022-08-21T21:37:11.476509148Z npm ERR!
    2022-08-21T21:37:11.477776868Z npm ERR! Failed at the taap@1.0.0 start script.
    2022-08-21T21:37:11.478919887Z npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    2022-08-21T21:37:11.555158523Z npm timing npm Completed in 9802ms
    2022-08-21T21:37:11.558920984Z
    2022-08-21T21:37:11.558951084Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    2022-08-21T21:37:11.558972684Z npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-08-21T21_37_11_479Z-debug.log
    /home/LogFiles/2022_08_21_lw0sdlwk0001T3_docker.log  (https://backendtaap.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2022_08_21_lw0sdlwk0001T3_docker.log)
    2022-08-21T04:07:01.722Z ERROR - Container backendtaap_0_4714aab5 for site backendtaap has exited, failing site start
```

Package.json

```
    {
  "name": "taap",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.0.0"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "config": "^3.3.7",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "^4.3.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
    "helmet": "^5.0.2",
    "joi": "^17.6.0",
    "joi-objectid": "^4.0.2",
    "joi-password-complexity": "^5.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongoose": "^6.4.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.1",
    "swagger-parser": "^10.0.3",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.4.0",
    "winston": "^3.6.0",
    "winston-mongodb": "^5.0.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you deploying this to Azure Container Instances or to an App Service?

Comment: Its a App Service.

Comment: looks to me like you're app settings variables aren't getting passed to the docker container environment, which is why you are getting these issues. Does this help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71804704/azure-app-service-how-to-use-environment-variables-in-docker-container

Comment: Im not using docker images. Im deploying from Github.

Comment: i have already setted environments variables